# Initial conditions in a circuit with two ideal transformers

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, frequency, passive-networks, laplace-transform

I don't know how to determine initial conditions in Laplace transform for a circuit or a system of circuits with ideal transformers with neither mutual inductance nor coupling coefficient is given. I have read something as to when to take initial conditions into account, but I can't be sure if those what I've read are applicable to my situation since they were provided as answer to a different question on this site. I leave a sample circuit below and my task is to analyse it in s-domain.[image]

Comment: Might the question actually be to find the steady-state RMS values assuming ideal transformers? I ask this because without any coupling factor and magnetization inductance, that's the only route you can take.

Comment: Andy, actually the question in the photo assumes the transformers are ideal, but that circuit is just a sample. What I want to learn is how to analyze a circuit with ideal transformers by using different methods I have learnt so far. So, the emphasis of this question is on Laplace transform of a circuit with transformers. Please do not focus on solving the problem. Thank you.

Comment: *What I want to learn is how to analyze a circuit with ideal transformers by using different methods I have learnt so far* <-- if this is a relevant part of your question you should add details of what you have learnt and possibly show an example analysis that you have performed so that anyone answering can now how to approach making an answer.

Comment: What have you learned about transformers so far? Any equations? Perhaps they can be applied to reduce the number of variables in this system, and make it soluble.

Comment: You're right. I am a newcomer indeed. I'm an undergraduate 2nd year student in electrical engineering. I have learnt analysing circuits with time domain, frequency domain by using phasors, frequency domain by using Laplace transform but only for circuits with no transformer. In order to set a basis for our discussion we can proceed on the sample circuit. I am struggling to analyse it by using Laplace transform, i.e., by using impedance and voltage reflections, converting elements into s domain elements by Laplace, solving circuit and converting back to t-domain by inverse Laplace.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal transformers become constant multipliers based upon turns ratio. \$v_2=3v_1\$, \$i_1=3i_2\$. Otherwise apply KVL and KCL as usual. Initial values are applied to the stand alone capacitors and inductors.

Comment: The question is why initial conditions are only taken into account when capacitor and inductor are stand alone. Moreover, this is a tricky question so that if you take initial conditions all zero and try to solve the problem by Laplace transforms, you'll see that whether or not you use RMS values for AC voltage sources, you'll get lengthy and troublesome equations at last.  I can follow the procedure for analysis of a circuit with transformers but I can't justify my decisions. Btw, if you ask why to analyse the circuit with specificly Laplace, it's because I desire ability to do it with it.

Answer (score 1):

Because no coupling coefficients are given, it is a reasonable approximation to assume they all are equal to 1.  The transformers shown don't give series resistance, either, so approximating them as zero is equally valid for approximations.  The voltage sources are sinusoidal, implying (mildly) that the transient solution is not of interest:  only the steady-state solution is sought. This permits you to use \$s\$-domain techniques to find the solution, then substitute \$s = j \omega\$ to get the phasor solution.  From this you can infer the real response.

As an aside, writing \$\omega=\frac{1}{2}\$ is sloppy:  the units should always be included. I imagine you meant to write \$\omega=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}\$.

Two of the given quantities are outlandishly large:  2 F and 4 H.  But to aid in theoretical understanding, they're fine.

Comment: Can we say that if a source is sinusoidal, it is reasonable to assume that the process takes place is of no transient phase and have already reached to steady state? I am also curious about that if s in Laplace transform is a compact term that accounts for both transient and steady state coefficients, i.e, since s=sigma+j*omega is sigma in this context correspond to a coefficient that accounts for transient phase? Is that why s=j*omega?

Comment: The approach I outlined amounts to ignoring transient phenomena by assuming that after enough time they all will have decayed to zero.  This is the case for a stable system, in which the real component of \$s\$ is negative.  Treating this real component as zero is equivalent to completely ignoring the transients and paying attention only to the steady-state result, which is the essence of the approach I've suggested.

Comment: Actually the reason is they are "ideal transformers"; the (linear) nonideal case is coupled inductors.

Answer (score 1):

You have drawn sinusoidal sources which have never started, they have been ON since time = minus eternity. Otherwise the sources should contain a step multiplier placed at their starting times. Thus there's no initial conditions, only a steady state operation exists. You must use a method where all transients are died, only the forced steady state operation is a part of the calculation. A good way for a single frequency circuit is to use the normal complex phasor method which is the single frequency steady state special case of the more general method where the Laplace transform s can be any complex number.

If some formal rule which is valid where you live and study forces you to give the initial conditions and start the circuit at t=0 you can calculate for the starting point t=0 the currents through the inductors and the charged voltages of the capacitors by finding at first the steady state solution and use them as your initial conditions. The (surely quite tricky) starting transient aware normal solution would give the same steady state solution, but only for time interval t = 0....+eternity